# In ngrx entity please tell me what type <V> is in EntityState<V>

Tags: typescript, ngrx, ngrx-entity

```
I just want to find what this type <V> for EntityState<V> is.
```

I just put the above in as code so that the V part shows up...( and I have no freaking idea how to search for something that is enclosed in chevrons or wtf those things are called)

I've searched for everything I can think of.  The ngrx docs use it in the documentation for https://v7.ngrx.io/guide/entity/interfaces and I found this tutorial that mentions it - https://medium.com/ngrx/introducing-ngrx-entity-598176456e15

```
... but I just can't figure out what is type <V>.
```

Here is the interface it is used in:

```
interface EntityState<V> {
  ids: string[] | number[];
  entities: { [id: string | id: number]: V };
}

This probably sounds retarded but HOW do I figure out the answer 
to this seemingly incredibly simple question?  What is <V>?
```

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it is using typescript.

```
interface EntityState<V> {
  ids: string[] | number[];
  entities: { [id: string | id: number]: V };
}
```

in the above interface you can picture that something would use the interface like this

```
class AnyClassname implements EntityState<ObjectName>{ ... }
```

`ObjectName` would be the object you want used as an entity or database entity.

the `ids` key is an array of either `number` or `string` and the `entities` key is essentially an object of the key (whether they are numbers or string with a value of `ObjectName`

Here is what it could look like (ObjectName is how I am representing an object, it could be a Todo or a User):

```
{
    ids: ['1','2'],
    entities: {
        '1': {
            ...ObjectName
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so <V> means the type will be an object?

Comment: @LeoKu it may be any type

Comment: @LeoKu I just used an object as an example. Typescript Generics is what it is and chances are if you were storing a bunch of `User` entities each `User` would have a `username`, `id`, and other data that would represent that user. The whole typescript generic thing is so you substitute `<V>` which I am guessing they used V to represent Value which is beside the point as the letter could be anything and you will usually see it as <T> to represent Type.